Error error de lectura NFC act=android.intent.action.MAIN
Estoy intentando leer los daos de un TAG NFC con android y java
sin embargo al acercar el tag el dispositivo reproduce sonido y recibo en el log el siguiente error.
getRecentTasks: taskId=526   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flag=268435456 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.example.nfctest/com.example.nfctest.MainActivity} }

utilizo la funcion de onNewIntent
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { Log.d(TAG,"onNewIntent()");
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.d(TAG,"intent.getAction() " + intent.getAction() + " intent.getExtras()" + intent.getExtras());}

pero no entra en dicha funcion.
esta es m configuracion dentro del Manifest
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

            </intent-filter>
           <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
               android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>

